# Cannot import module to begin basic Flask app

Tags: flask

So I'm following a beginners tutorial on Flask and for whatever reason am getting an error on what is essentially the very first step.

I first created an "app" directory where I created a python file for "**init**.py" which contains the following code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

I then created a "routes.py" python file in the same directory:

```
from app import app


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Finally (and this is where the problem stems from), I created a python file named "microblog.py" which is located in the same folder as the "app" directory:

```
from app import app
```

I then go to my virtual environment and run (using cmd windows):

```
set FLASK_APP=microblog.py
```

So far so good, however when I try to run the following code in cmd:

```
flask run
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'app' from 'app' (C:\Users\Grae_\microblog\app\__init__.py)
```

If any further clarification is needed, here are my file locations:

```
C:\Users\Grae_\microblog
C:\Users\Grae_\microblog\app
C:\Users\Grae_\microblog\__init__.py
C:\Users\Grae_\microblog\routes.py
C:\Users\Grae_\microblog\venv
C:\Users\Grae_\microblog\microblog.py
```

Apologies if this is really obvious, I'm just obviously very new to Flask and have been stuck on this for a while.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is on python package "app". The directory should have a file named `__init__.py` instead of `init.py`.

For example, you rename the file `init.py` to `__init__.py` and replace content with below code it should work

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


def start():
    from app import routes


start()
```

Comment: Hey sorry but what do you mean by change init.py to init.py? They are the same name

Comment: Hello @GraeCumming, was this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

test.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Index!"

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return "Members"

@app.route("/members/<string:name>/")
def getMember(name):
    return name</string:name>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

In command prompt, run the command-

```
python test.py
```

Try the URLs in your browser:

http://127.0.0.1:5000/

http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello

http://127.0.0.1:5000/members

http://127.0.0.1:5000/members/Karan/